# how do i prevent minimize application from minimizing all forms?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have an application with three forms. The main form is created automatically and the others are created manually at runtime.

I need to minimaze the main form if the user clicks on minimize but do not minimize all other forms. Is it something I have to edit in the project source or it is the VCL behavior that I can't avoid?

I have searched before posting this question and I found some references about how to prevent the form from being minimized which is not the case here.

Comment: This is default behavior (hardcoded in the `TCustomForm.WMSysCommand`). Write your own `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message handler and do not pass the message to the `Application.WndProc`. Or process the application message and do not minimize the whole application, but the main form.

Comment: @Victoria Isn't this behaviour determined by window ownership?

Comment: @David, I can read in `TCustomForm.WMSysCommand` that if the command is `SC_MINIMIZE` and form is the main application form, the message is dispatched to the application object's `WndProc`. Different handling is done for forms that are not main from there (`RequestAlign` is called).

Comment: Yes, first you need to set MainFormOnTaskbar false so that secondary forms are not owned by the main form, otherwise they will be hidden when the main form  minimizes. Then proceed with sys command handling. Alternatively create secondary forms unowned. A search on params.wndparent will lead to countless examples.

Comment: ... Of course the catch is you'll break other related behavior, like activating the main form won't help any secondary form to come forward for instance.